# Get maximum of 3 numbers and with this respective name

Tags: r

I am trying to get the maximum of 3 numbers along with its respective name assigned. But I get the maximum of the 3 numbers but the name assigned is not retrieved the last column as default.

```
maximum=function(a,b,c)
{
  max=a
  max1 = "aaa";
  if(b>max)
    max=b
    max1 = "bbb";
  if(c>max)
    max=c
  max1 = "ccc";
  print(paste(max1,max));
}
```

I get my error output as below:

```
> maximum(3,2,1)
[1] "ccc 3"
```

Expected output:

```
"aaa 3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function would work if you add parenthesis in your `if` statement since `if` without parenthesis would only consider 1st statement inside the `if` block. Hence, all the `max1` values would be over-written by `"ccc"` in the last statement which gives you wrong output.

```
maximum=function(a,b,c) {
   max=a
   max1 = "aaa";
   if(b>max) {
      max=b
      max1 = "bbb"
   }
   if(c>max) {
     max=c
     max1 = "ccc"
   }
  print(paste(max1,max));
}

maximum(3, 2, 1)
#[1] "aaa 3"

 maximum(1, 2, 10)
#[1] "ccc 10"
```

---

However, here is an alternate solution if you prefer to pass 3 variables differently.

```
maximum <- function(a, b, c) {
  inds <- which.max(c(a, b, c))
  vals <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
  print(paste(vals[inds], c(a, b, c)[inds]))
}

maximum(3, 2, 1)
#[1] "aaa 3"

maximum(3, 2, 10)
#[1] "ccc 10"
```

Answer (score -1):

We can also write the function with either creating a named vector or a data.frame and then subset the rows and `paste`

```
maxfn <- function(a, b, c){

  do.call(paste, subset( data.frame(col1 = strrep(letters[1:3], 3), 
           col2 = c(a, b,  c)), col2 == max(col2)))
  }

maxfn(3, 2, 1)
#[1] "aaa 3"

maxfn(3, 2, 10)
#[1] "ccc 10"
```